# SICP 3.6 - Rand procedure and local state variables

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, sicp

I'm having difficulties with exercise 3.6 in SICP.
They give the following code for a pseudo-random number generator:

```
(define rand
  (let ((x random-init))
    (lambda ()
      (set! x (rand-update x))
      x)))
```

To which I added, for testing purposes:

```
(define (rand-update x) (+ x 1))
(define random-init 4)
```

Repeated applications produces

```
> (rand)
5
> (rand)
6
> (rand)
7
```

as hoped, although I can't see why this works.
Anyway, exercise 3.6 asks us to modify `rand` so that it takes a single argument, instructing it to either `'generate` or `'reset`.

First things first, I tried to set up a rand with conditions that would generate. However, I stumbled at this first hurdle.

```
(define (rand-new instruction)
  (let ((x random-init))
    (cond ((eq? instruction 'generate)
          (lambda ()
            (set! x (rand-update x))
            x)))))
```

gives me

```
> ((rand-new 'generate))
5
> ((rand-new 'generate))
5
> ((rand-new 'generate))
5
```

as does moving the let expression into the conidition, like this:

```
(define (rand-new instruction)
  (cond ((eq? instruction 'generate)
         (let ((x random-init))
           (lambda ()
             (set! x (rand-update x))
             x)))))
```

So why does the first function work, and the new one doesn't?
Is it to do with the use of conditions? Or with the addition of an parameter?

**UPDATE (19/03/20)**

Reading the next section on the environment model of computation (§3.2) gave me the theory necessary to figure out what was going on.
I ended up with

```
(define (random-number-generator initial update)
  (define (generate)
    (begin (set! initial (update initial))
          initial))
  (define (reset new-value)
    (begin (set! initial new-value)
           initial))
  (define (dispatch message)
    (cond ((eq? message 'generate) (generate))
          ((eq? message 'reset) reset)
          (else "Procedure not found!")))
  dispatch)

(define rand (random-number-generator 5 rand-update))
```

Comment: "Although I can't see why this works" -> then, you need to spend time understanding _why_ it works, before trying to modify it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point for understanding why the first version works (and why the other doesn't) is in the first three lines:

```
(define rand
  (let ((x random-init))
    (lambda ()
```

As you can see, the name `rand` is assigned to a `lambda` - but before doing that a variable `x` is created in a scope *outside* of the `lambda`, meaning: that no matter how many times we call `rand`, the value in `x` will "remember" its previous value, which we set in the previous call: `(set! x (rand-update x))`.

So, you *must* respect the placement of that `let` and that `lambda`, otherwise the procedure you create won't have any "memory" between invocations. Besides, I don't think the exercise is asking you to create your own `random` procedure, it'd be enough to create a wrapper around the built-in procedures that accepts the required messages:

```
(define (make-rand)
  (λ (msg)
    (case msg
      ('reset (λ (seed) (random-seed seed)))
      ('generate (random)))))

(define rand (make-rand))
```

For example:

```
((rand 'reset) 42)
(rand 'generate)
=> 0.07337258110323383
(rand 'generate)
=> 0.0887121382290788
((rand 'reset) 42)
(rand 'generate)
=> 0.07337258110323383
(rand 'generate)
=> 0.0887121382290788
```

If you decide to implement your own version of `random`, try to keep the procedures separate (as I did above), if you put everything in a single place things will get confusing pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not contained in our 'random' procedure. `x` is containded in the procedure that *makes* our 'random' procedure.  The shape of the solution is:

```
(define (make-rand)
  (define x 0)
  ...
  <proc>)

(define my-rand (make-rand))

((my-rand 'reset) 42)
(my-rand 'generate)
(my-rand 'generate)
```

So `make-rand` returns a procedure `<proc>` which:

1. given the message `'generate` returns the next random number.
2. given the message `'reset` returns *yet another* procedure that takes a new value and assigns it to x.

Using define (named procedures) `make-rand` could be:

```
(define (make-rand)
  (define x 0)
  (define (set-x! new-x)
    (set! x new-x))
  (define (dispatch message)
    (cond
      ((eq? message 'generate)
       (set! x (rand-update x))
       x)
      ((eq? message 'reset)
       set-x!)
      (else ((error "Unknown Message - " message)))))
  dispatch) ; 'dispatch' returned and assigned to my-rand
```

The `'reset` message returns a procedure, e.g., `(my-rand 'reset)` returns `set-x!` so `((my-rand 'reset) 42)` is equivalent to `(set-x! 42)`.

We could also implement `make-rand` using lambdas (anonymous procedures):

```
(define (make-rand)
  (let ((x 0))
    (lambda (message) ; lambda returned and assigned to my-rand
      (cond
        ((eq? message 'generate)
         (set! x (rand-update x))
         x)
        ((eq? message 'reset)
         (lambda (new-x) (set! x new-x)))
        (else ((error "Unknown Message - " message)))))))
```

In either case, as Oscar explains, `x` maintains it's value because it is outside the scope of `<proc>`/`my-rand`.  This is described in §3.2 and then implemented in §4.1.

Comment: Thanks - actually, the necessary theory ended up being covered in §3.2. This is one of the mildly frustrating things about SICP, sometimes you need to read ahead to do the exercises! 

In the end I did something similar to you, and have updated the initial post.